# Query Performance: Aggregate before with derived tables or after when joining a lot of tables?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm hoping the answer to this question isn't "depends".

I have to write a report that is a summary of class data.  Each class contains aggregated student data, such as grade, attendance, etc.  Some of this data, like grade is aggregate data of all graded assignments.

The query works, but I realize I have written an unmaintainable monster joining together about 15 tables.  If I rewrote the query using derived tables would I help or hurt performance?

Comment: "it depends"! on the actual query, indexes, etc...Plase be more specific

Answer (score 0):

As far as **performance** you could get improvements by adding indexes. Joins will be super fast.

As far as **maintainability** (and readability) derived tables could help. Also, you could create views in order to separate the logic.

Furthermore, you could consider creating tables with aggregate data and then just run a simple `select * from summary`

Answer (score 0):

Actually ended up being a performance boost to use derived tables.  I realize I had a fairly poor question.  Let me give a small snippet...

Aggregate after JOINs.  Cost .937

```
DECLARE @0 INT = 141;

SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, 
    CAST(CAST(COUNT(haid.mastered_date) AS DECIMAL) / CAST(COUNT(sa.id) AS DECIMAL) * 100 AS DECIMAL(4, 1)) AS mastery_perc
FROM reporting_saved_reports r
JOIN reporting_saved_reports_sections sr ON sr.report_id = r.id
JOIN ums_ae_instructor_section_order_user isou ON isou.instructor_section_id = sr.section_id
JOIN ums_users u ON u.id = isou.user_id
JOIN reporting_states sa ON sa.tutor_id = r.Tutor_Id
    AND sa.business_type IN ('B', r.business_type)
    AND sa.haid = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN reporting_wrapup_haid haid ON haid.tutor_id = r.Tutor_Id
    AND haid.section_id = isou.instructor_section_id
    AND haid.user_id = isou.user_id
    AND haid.state_id = sa.id
    AND haid.mastered_date BETWEEN r.from_date AND r.to_date
WHERE r.id = @0
GROUP BY u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name
ORDER BY u.last_name, u.first_name
;
```

Aggregate before with derived table, then join.  Cost .546

```
DECLARE @0 INT = 141;

WITH wr AS (
    SELECT r.id AS report_id, r.Tutor_Id, r.from_date, r.to_date, r.business_type, sr.section_id, isou.user_id
    FROM reporting_saved_reports r
    JOIN reporting_saved_reports_sections sr ON sr.report_id = r.id
    JOIN ums_ae_instructor_section_order_user isou ON isou.instructor_section_id = sr.section_id
    WHERE r.id = @0
)
SELECT dual.user_id, dual.first_name, dual.last_name,
    CAST(CAST(haid.mastered_count AS DECIMAL) / CAST(dual.state_count AS DECIMAL) * 100 AS DECIMAL(4, 1)) AS mastery_perc
FROM (
    SELECT wr.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, COUNT(sa.id) AS state_count
    FROM ums_users u
    JOIN wr ON wr.user_id = u.id
    JOIN reporting_states sa ON sa.tutor_id = wr.Tutor_Id
        AND sa.business_type IN ('B', wr.business_type)
        AND sa.haid = 'Y'
    GROUP BY wr.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name
) dual
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT haid.user_id, COUNT(haid.mastered_date) AS mastered_count
    FROM reporting_wrapup_haid haid
    JOIN wr ON wr.Tutor_Id = haid.tutor_id
        AND wr.section_id = haid.section_id
        AND wr.user_id = haid.user_id
        AND haid.mastered_date <= wr.to_date
    GROUP BY haid.user_id
) haid ON haid.user_id = dual.user_id
ORDER BY dual.last_name, dual.first_name
;
```